# How to prevent HTML elements from moving due to other large elements

Tags: html, css, position

I have a section of my webpage that looks like this [image: correct setup]

This is how I want this section to be set up. I can easily copy and paste more "cell" elements to make more "cells" for a picture and text below it. However, if the text on one of the elements is too large, it moves all of the other elements and messing the neat matrix setup.
[image: mess up]

If the text is too large, I would rather have it just get cut off and keep the shape of the matrix, rather than shifting all the elements in the matrix to make room for the text. How could I accomplish this?

My HTML looks like this

```
            <div class="about_box">
         <div class="container">
            <h3>Our Team</h3>
            <div class="col-md-3 row_1">
                <img src="images/a1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                <h5><a href="#">nonummy</a></h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn_2">more</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 row_1">
                <img src="images/a2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                <h5><a href="#">euismod</a></h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn_2">more</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 row_1">
                <img src="images/a3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                <h5><a href="#">tincidunt</a></h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn_2">more</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 row_1">
                <img src="images/a4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                <h5><a href="#">laoreet</a></h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn_2">more</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 row_1">
                <img src="images/a4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                <h5><a href="#">laoreet</a></h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn_2">more</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 row_1">
                <img src="images/a4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                <h5><a href="#">laoreet</a></h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn_2">more</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 row_1">
                <img src="images/a4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                <h5><a href="#">laoreet</a></h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn_2">more</a>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

Each div with a class of `col-md-3 row_1` is a single element in the matrix

Answer (score 0):

You can use a text-overflow: ellipsis for the text which uses ( ... ) to represent the overflowing text.Also you need to set the overflow of the div to hidden.
And then use the bootstrap grids accordingly.

Comment: Did the text get hidden? or is it the same issue..? Give a height for the div containing the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
<style>
.row_1{
height:auto;
max-height:120px;
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
```

Comment: For some reason, if I do this and set the max-height to 24% or lower, it works! But if I set it to anything higher than 24%, I have the same problem again. I can't do with a max-height that low however as it compresses the height of the photos by a lot and mushes everything together.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width in %. For example: `div.container div {width: 20%;}`

Comment: Manually setting the width allows for more elements per row, but doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Why did you have to set them manually? `div.container div {width: 20%;}` should work for all of your 'cells'. However, it's a bit difficult to help you without seeing how your code works.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use PHP to trim lengthy text. Have a look at this function:

```
function smartTrimString($str, $len){
    $str=trim($str);
    if (strlen($str)>$len)
        return substr($str,0,$len)."...";
    else
        return $str;
}
```